# Git command not working in init container

Tags: git, docker, kubernetes

```
initContainers:
  - name: git-clone-openg2p
    image: bitnami/odoo
    command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
    args: ['apt-get git && git clone https://github.com/repo.git && git clone https://github.com/repo.git /bitnami/odoo']
    volumeMounts:
      - name: odoo-data
        mountPath: /bitnami/odoo
```

I need to add add-ons by cloning git repository into `/bitnami/odoo`.
This is my init container configuration in yaml file. When I `helm install` and create pod it says "Invalid operation git" in the logs of pod.

Comment: This seems like an odd path to me; why not build your application code into an (immutable) image and just use it, instead of hoping the APT repository and GitHub will both be accessible every time every replica of the pod starts?

Comment: The path was kind of default for bitnami odoo image."build your application code into an (immutable) image and just use it" yeah this works too i guess but have not tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `apt-get git`

The correct syntax is

```
apt-get install --yes git
```

Comment: Thanks.Also one more thing apt-get update before apt-install:)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no command `apt-get get`, you probably want:

```
apt-get install -y git
```